# How to postback from jQuery Dialog to the parent page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a pageA.aspx. In it I open a jQuery dialog with an iframe containing the pageB.asxp.

```
var dlg = $('#dialog1').html('<iframe id="ifrm"></iframe>');
dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true
});

dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));


    $('#buttonOpenDialog').click(function () {
        var url = '../PageB.aspx';
        $("#dialog1>#ifrm").attr("src", url);
        $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Until here is all alright. Now I submit the form and when postback finishes I want to close this dialog I do it like that:

```
function closePopup() {
    parent.$("#dialog1").dialog('close');
   __doPostBack();
```

}

and I want to refresh the parent page pageA.aspx without doing the ugly

```
__doPostBack()
```

How Can I accomplish this?
thank you

EDIT: It seems is a complex issue. Please get involved ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden button in parent page. And when the modal closed, generate the hidden button's click event. It will refresh the parent page.

```
dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
           // btnHidden is the id of the hidden button.
           document.getElementById('<%=btnHidden.ClientID%>').click();
           // To refresh gridview when user close dialog
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the _target attribute of the submitted form to _parent . The result of the POST will then be displayed in the parent frame (pageA.aspx)

```
<form target="_parent">
</form>
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Is this what the CrossPage Postback do? Like that I'd have to handle the event in the target page, right?

Comment: I've tryed and it's not what i need. This way when form is submited the dialog is maximized on the parent page. Furthermore i have more than one button that makes postbacks. It should be apply only in desired button.